# How can I convert my ImageMagick commands to Wand (Python)?

Tags: python, magickwand, wand

I'm trying to move a program over to Python, and part if this relies on a shell script where I process some images with ImageMagick. I've installed wand, the ctypes-based ImageMagick bindings for Python but I can't figure out how to get my original code translated.

Here's the command line code, which uses CONVERT and OPTIMIZE.

`convert -delay $theDelay /path/to/images/$theDateStamp*.png -layers optimize -write /path/to/animationFolder/NewAnimatedGIFfile-$theDateStamp.gif -delete 1--1 -resize 200x200 /path/to/animationFolder/NewStaticGIFthumb-$theDateStamp-t.gif`

Basically, the script goes to a folder where I have downloaded time-stamped images and creates an animated GIF with only those images that meet the timestamp requirement; saves it to the animation folder; then it creates a thumbnail of that animated gif by deleting the frames, resizing, and saving the single gif image to the same folder, with a "-t" addition to the name.

Comment: This is discussed on Wand mailing list: http://librelist.com/browser//wand/2013/3/27/trying-to-move-some-command-line-imagemagick-code-to-python/#7690ce11c6fba890345235d94fd8d16c